# Set .attr to dynamically created button

Tags: jquery

I try to pass val with dynamic create button.

First I create button with this code:

```
<td id=\"row-delete" + length + "\" class=\"row-status\">
   <input type='image' id='btnDel' src='Images/trash.png' style='height:24px;width:24px;' />
</td>
```

This line add my button to table column.

After that I try to add a parameter to this button :

```
$("#btnDel").attr("val", "test value");
```

And on the and for button click I use:

```
$('#file-list').on('click', '#btnDel', function () {
    alert(this.val);
});
```

On click I always get `undefined`, if I try to use `id` not val than I get `btnDel`, not `test-value`.

Can I pass something with dynamically created button?

Thanks

Comment: instead of `this.val` use `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

Comment: `$("#btnDel").attr("val", "test value");` to `$("#btnDel").val( "test value");`

Comment: @Kartikeya,@Amit Garg, thanx both for answers i try both things,and always get empty or null. Sorry maybe i was not clear enough (english is not my better side), this html for button is created in jquery file,not html, because that I write dynamic, maybe that is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handler `this` is a DOM object, not a jQuery object. You can either do `this.getAttribute('val')` or `$(this).attr('val')`.

Also, please note that HTML5 custom attributes should start with `data-`.

```
$("#btnDel").attr("data-val", "test value");
```

Then you can use `this.dataset.val` or `$(this).data('val')`.

Comment: thanx for answer, i write comment with same thing, i get empty, null or undefined value, when i try your answers, like i wrote maybe i was not clear enough because my English. I created html dimacly in jquery code, maybe that is problem.